# Securing OpenLDAP on Debian Buster

Tags: ldap, openldap

would [this](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.ldap-directory.en.html) still be the way of securing an OpenLDAP server on Debian 9 (Stretch) and 10 (Buster). See **Section 11.7.3.3. Securing LDAP Data Exchanges**. Unfortunately the Debian manual seems to always be a few distros behind. Although its a home network, I'm still no keen on having passwords traveling in clear between hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Always use TLS to secure data transmitted and let the client authenticate the server to which it sends credentials.

Yes. The section [Securing LDAP Data Exchanges](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.ldap-directory.en.html#id-1.14.10.9.5) seems to be sufficient to properly configure TLS. You should consider to automate things especially for certificate and key renewal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. I guess my question was whether the above guide was applicable to Debian Buster? Apologies for not wording the question correctly.

Comment: Edit my answer.